How to accurately calculate CPU usage of a process with OSHI compared to Task Manager?
I'm developing a resource monitoring system for a game using LibGDX and the OSHI library to get CPU and memory usage information. However, I'm facing issues when comparing the CPU usage values returned by the OSHI API with those shown in the Windows Task Manager.
Currently, I'm using the getProcessCpuLoadCumulative() method to retrieve the cumulative CPU usage of a process, but the values returned differ significantly from those displayed in the Task Manager. I've tried several approaches, but I still can't get the values to match.
Here's the code I'm using to calculate CPU usage:
public String getCPU() {
    lastCPUCheckTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    if (lastCPUCheckTime >= UPDATE_INTERVAL) {
        lastCPUCheckTime = 0;
        
        // Get current process info
        osProcess = operatingSystem.getProcess(operatingSystem.getProcessId());
        
        // Get cumulative CPU usage
        double cpuUsage = osProcess.getProcessCpuLoadCumulative(osProcess) * 100;
        
        cachedCPU = String.format("%.2f%%", cpuUsage);
    }
    return cachedCPU;
}

The problem is that the CPU value returned by getProcessCpuLoadCumulative() is out of sync with what I see in the Task Manager. For example, while the Task Manager shows around 30% CPU usage for my process, the value obtained via OSHI can be significantly lower or higher.
How can I correctly calculate the CPU usage of a specific process with OSHI so that the value matches what is displayed in the Windows Task Manager?  And more specifically:

Is there any way to account for the "logical processors" and the cores on which the process is running to obtain a more accurate reading?

Does OSHI provide a way to identify the cores that the process is using and calculate CPU usage based on those specific cores?



I'm the primary maintainer of OSHI.
The getProcessCpuLoadCumulative() method (which takes no arguments) returns cumulative CPU usage since the process started, which is a common output on *nix views of process CPU.  However, the Windows Task manager displays current usage (over some time period).
The FAQ describes a bit more how it's calculated:

CPU usage is generally calculated as (active time / active+idle time). On a multi-processor system, the "idle" time can be accrued on each/any of the logical processors.
For per-Process CPU ticks, there is no "idle" counter available, so the calculation ends up being (active time / up time). It is possible for a multi-threaded process to accrue more active clock time than elapsed clock time, and result in CPU usage over 100% (e.g., on a 4-processor system it could in theory reach 400%). This interpretation matches the value displayed in ps or top on Unix-based operating systems. However, Windows scales process CPU usage to the system, so that the sum of all Process CPU percentages can never exceed 100% (ignoring roundoff errors). On a 4-processor system, a single-threaded process maximizing usage of one logical processor will show (on Windows) as 25% usage. OSHI's calculation for Process CPU load will report the Unix-based calculation in this class, which would be closer to 100%.
If you want per-Process CPU load to match the Windows Task Manager display, you should divide OSHI's calculation by the number of logical processors.

You should be using the getProcessCpuLoadBetweenTicks(OSProcess proc) method, with a previous version of the process, and after a suitable time delay.
However, even polling for ticks regularly and accounting for number of logical processors may have small differences with the Task Manager unless you have precisely synchronized both the tick collection and delay time.
In addition, there is counter precision to consider. Windows ticks, while reported in 100s of nanoseconds, increment every 1/64 of a second, meaning any single tick value can be over or under by up to this amount.  With a short tick delay interval and many processors, these can add up and be much more significant.
To address your more detailed questions regarding per-processor statistics, for a process, note that a specific process may switch between processors whenever a new thread starts (likely), and occasionally even for the same thread (less likely but possible).  To identify per-thread CPU, you would need to use the getThreadDetails() method to independently calculate that CPU usage, but you still wouldn't know which processor, and you'd have to try to correlate the usage with per-processor CPU usage accounting for all processes on the system.  Possible to do with statistical tools, but unlikely to be very useful.
The oshi-demo module includes a GUI which includes a Process display.  You can look at its code to see a more appropriate way of measuring ticks that more closely resembles the Task Manager.
